# How to change the order of the months for navigation grouped by year using PHP & SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

How to change the order of the months for navigation grouped by year using PHP & SQL 
I'm making a navigation for the WordPress posts grouped by year using SQL.
My code is working but I'd like to change the order of months like below.

**Current results**

> 2019　 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
>
> 2018　 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

**I'd like to change the order of month like this**

> 2019　 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
>
> 2018　 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

```
$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$year_prev = null;
$months = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH( post_date ) AS month,
    YEAR( post_date ) AS year,
    COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( )
    and post_type = 'post'
    GROUP BY month , year
    ORDER BY post_date DESC");
foreach($months as $month) :
$year_current = $month->year;
if ($year_current != $year_prev){
if ($year_prev != null){?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $month->year; ?>
<ul>
<?php } ?>
    <li><a href="/archive/<?php echo $month->year; ?>/<?php echo date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?>"><?php echo date("n", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)) ?></a></li>
<?php $year_prev = $year_current;
endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try instead of `ORDER BY post_date DESC` just `ORDER BY year DESC, month ASC`

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment, it worked by using "ORDER BY year DESC, month ASC" insted of "ORDER BY post_date DESC".

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ORDER BY post_date DESC` by `ORDER BY year DESC, month ASC` in your statement.
MySQL allows sorting with more than one column and with a direction for every column.